# Benchmarking code precisely

Tags: c#, .net, benchmarking, performance-testing

I need to measure performance of my code with maximum possible precision.

Currently I'm using:
- Stopwatch to measure timing
- Set process affinity to use the same CPU core all time
- Set thread priority to the maximum
- Perform warm-up run before measuring
- Run test 1000 times and calculate average

However, I'm still having difference between benchmark runs (about 1% max). Any ideas how to make this measurement more precise?

Comment: This may sound snarky, but: write your own OS that doesn't run 200 other processes at the same time? Seriously, any other running process will affect the outcome of the benchmark of yours. Is 1% difference really that much on just 1000 runthroughs? =)

Comment: Really, don't worry about 1% difference on a non-real-time OS!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Run warm-up code for at least 10 seconds before starting my measurements. It's necessary to ensure CPU is running at the maximal speed.
2. Measure the *lowest* run time, rather than average.

With these 2 improvements, I've achieved very stable measurement results.

Answer (score 2):

This may be obvious, but your CPU isn't dedicated to your single process. It also takes charge of a lot of other things for OS and hardware.

Also, the memory usage, HDD usage, and the behaviour of GC could vary between executions. Maybe your computations needs virtual memory, which is much slower than RAM access. And so on...

About GC, you could try to play with different settings of "GCSettings.LatencyMode " to see if it changes anything (see http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/sasha/archive/2008/08/10/low-latency-gc-in-net-3-5.aspx for example).

In a single session on the same computer, Stopwatch is quite accurate : if duration differs between execution, it's probably not because of a lack of accuracy in measure, it's because the process itself doesn't take always the same time...
Obviously, each "iteration" of your test should take at least a few hundred milliseconds, Stopwatch will never be able to measure a duration in nanoseconds...

And 1% variation isn't surprising at all.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason that the performance would differ, such as an external component?

1% variation isn't much over 1000 runs in performance, especially if it is reliant on anything external such as connection to a DB or service.

Stopwatch is the most accurate method of measuring time so I wouldn't be concerned about that

Comment: Are any other processes running? Can you set the affinity of the CPU core to anything other than CPU0?

When you say 1% difference, what are the times ranging from and to? Are the outliers rare or is the timing result fairly spread (the standard deviation)